# Access spring web application context beans in EL expression

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring MVC and have the following situation:

In WEB-INF/demoshop-servlet.xml I have the following line:

```
<bean id="someBean" class="com.xxx.xxx.web.SomeBean" />
```

I also have a JSP that contains a line like:

```
${someBean.someAttribute}
```

I expected that the attribute is read from the bean when the page is rendered but it's not. The expression is just ignored. (While other EL expressions with objects introduced in a ModelMap in the controller are evaluated correctly.)

In order to debug this a little I inserted the following to the JSP:

```
<% System.out.println(application.getAttribute("someBean")); %>
```

Which prints `null`.

**What is missing, or what am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring beans are not automatically made available to the JSP page, you have to put the bean in the appropriate scope (application, session, request, or page).  You ave at least these options:

1. Add the bean to the `Model` in your Controller
2. Extend a `View` class and add the bean to the `Model`.

Comment: I tried the second idea, and it worked. Thanks! I added a bean of class InternalResourceViewResolver in the same xml file and added a property 'viewClass' that points to a new sub-class of JstlView which just calls setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true) in the constructor.

Comment: In fact, you don't need to subclass the InternalResourceViewResolver or JstlView. You can simply declare it in your context and set the exposeContextBeansAsAttributes, like this:<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/> </bean> I have tested this with spring 3.1

Answer (score 1):

Here have a method, you can get Spring bean in JSP file without Java code. 
Setup a Spring Web MVC XML file and add 1 property in viewResolver:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Now, You can get bean content in JSP like that:

```
<c:out value="${ bean.value }" />
```

Comment: Thank! This property works with org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver as wel! Pay attention to use bean.value instead of bean.getValue()! :)